# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/enterprise/universal/i18n/LocalStringsImpl

Tags: java, glassfish, classnotfoundexception, asadmin

When I undeployed the war file(glassfish) using asadmin and when I try restarting the glassfish it throws error, what can be the possible problem may be jar file or something is missing.

```
/opt/glassfishv3/glassfish/bin/asadmin undeploy war-name
/opt/glassfishv3/glassfish/bin/asadmin deploy war-name.war
./etc/init.d/glassfish restart
```

---

```
Starting Glassfish ...
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/enterprise/universal/i18n/LocalStringsImpl
        at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.AsadminMain.<clinit>(AsadminMain.java:94)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.enterprise.universal.i18n.LocalStringsImpl
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem arised from a missing jar file that is **common-util.jar**  [More about common util jar files](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/c/Downloadcommonutil301jar.htm)
The missing file comes under the above mentioned jar file

```
jar -tvf common-util.jar
--o/p set of files inside the jar as below

com.sun.enterprise.universal.i18n.LocalStringsImpl.class
```